# Add leading zeros into binary

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi i would like to add leading zeros into binary to make it to have 8 digits. I've tried using `zfill()` but it doesnt seem to work and i have no idea how to use `format()` cause all the answers i've found are all keeping the `0b` which i dont want that.

Here's what i've tried:

```py
lenToBin = bin(payloadLength).replace("0b", "")
        if payloadLength == 30 or payloadLength == 31:
            binResult = lenToBin.zfill(3)
        else:
            binResult = lenToBin.zfill(2)
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you want:

```
lenToBin = bin(payloadLength).replace("0b", "").zfill(8)
```